# I need a simple example of asp.net routing

Tags: asp.net, routes

if the user type

```
http://myweb/mysite.aspx (file does not exist)
```

I want them to go to

```
http://myweb/site.aspx (file does exist)
```

My goal is to make a bilingual website (including url) but without having to make physical file

this would be one file

```
http://myweb/acceuil.aspx
http://myweb/home.aspx
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440883/mass-301-redirects-in-asp-net-including-pages-that-need-to-redirect-to-a-differe

Comment: Are you looking for all requested pages which don't exist to go to site.aspx or only mysite.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but this is the best turtorial for the question you asked:

[How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx)

Comment: Does this require the presence of the old page?  If so, adding a simple script to the page solves that problem without a CustomRouteHandler.  I think what he wants is a way to specify the old and new pages by name, without having to leave the old pages on the server.

Comment: I used the first url, "How to: Use Routing with Web Forms". You can remove everything else under it if you want. thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not routing; that is a [redirect](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=301+redirect+asp.net&aq=f&oq=&aqi=).

`_rick_shott` seems to have the mojo on routing bad urls into a 301 redirect.  I upvoted his answer.  You should check out his HTTPModule solution.

Comment: with redirect, you have to create a file, I want to use the routing module so I wont have o do that

Comment: Do you care about search engine optimization?

Comment: @Fredou: You don't have to create a file if you use an HTTPModule

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, add a customErrors and error node as follows:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorDisplayPage.aspx">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://myweb/site.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

This will displayErrorDisplayPage.aspx for all unmanaged errors except for 404 errors (which are "page not found").  For 404 errors, the browser will redirect to the site.aspx page.

Comment: AFAIK this will redirect ALL 404's to the new page, unless this is in a location element.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.71).aspx for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that is what the poster was asking for - all not found pages to go to site.aspx.